# i would like to add a bcc to all mails going out from my postfix

Tags: postfix-mta

i have a forum which sends out many automatic mails. i would like to gather the mails to have an overview. how can i add a bcc to all outgoing mails excluding some mail-subjects or early hours when especially many mails are sent?

Answer (score 3):

There is an `always_bcc` parameter in Postfix you could set for that.  Or modify the configuration of your forum to add yourself as a Bcc: for these mails.  Be aware of the privacy issues of such configuration though (IANAL of course).  Check the documentation on [The Postfix site](http://postfix.org/start.html)

Answer (score 2):

If your forum always sends out mail as a specific sender, there is `sender_bcc_maps`.

```
sender_bcc_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/bcc_senders
```

`bcc_senders` contains

```
forum@example.com    your_bcc_recipient@example.com
```

Then you can add filters on the recipient side to exclude the mail you want to ignore.

Answer (score 1):

If you're FORUM software is running on a server that is either hosting with Postfix, or relaying it's mail messages through another host that you control (and is running Postfix) [presumptions made from the post being tagged with Postfix].

- Two partial solutions have been specified for getting a blind carbon copy by [Keltia](https://stackoverflow.com/users/16143/keltia) use always_bcc and [Devdas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/116461/devdas) use sender_bcc_maps.
- In the forum software, you could always modify the software to send an extra copy to your designated BCC email account.

To provide the filtering:

> Blockquote
>   excluding some mail-subjects or early hours when especially many mails are sent

- If your BCC destination is a unix account then you can use .forward to send the message to processing by another script. Procmail has some filtering capabilities that might be helpful here.
- Update the forum software logic to specify when you want a BCC.